# command to grep the lines between these two curly braces

Tags: grep

```
 typedef enum bit [3:0] {
    V18 = 4'h0,
    V19 = 4'h1,
    V20 = 4'h2,
    V21 = 4'h3,
    V22 = 4'h4,
    V23 = 4'h5,
    V24 = 4'h6,
    V25 = 4'h7,
    V26 = 4'h8,
    V27 = 4'h9,
    V28 = 4'ha,
    V29 = 4'hb,
    V30 = 4'hc,
    V31 = 4'hd,
    V32 = 4'he
  } E17 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
sed -n '/{/,/}/{//!p}' file
```

- Just have the matching pattern inside the first block `'/<StartPattern>/` and the second matching pattern into print until `/<endPattern>/` which is separated by comma.

here start pattern is an open brace and end pattern is a close brace. So it will be like `/{/,/}/`

- To exclude matching patterns while printing the output `{//!p}`
- `-n` to suppress automatic printing of pattern space (source: MAN page)

Comment: Can you explain how is it working?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav updated, let me know if u have any Qs.